# Creating an array of integers or NSUIntegers in objective C

Tags: objective-c

How is an array created for integers or NSUIntegers in objective c?

The thing is I want an array which I can change often(NSMutableArray ?) but when I try to addObject:someInt or someNSUInteger I get a warning about "without cast" and when that code executes the app crashes.

What is the fastest way to set this up? and I dont know the size of the array. It should be dynamic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NSUInteger is nothing but a typedef-ed unsigned int.  NSMutableArrays only accept objects, which I think is your problem.  Try using [NSNumber](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead.

Comment: I still get a warning  Passing argument 1 of 'removeObjectAtIndex:' makes integer from pointer without a cast when trying to remove it and I also get a warning Assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast when assigning imageSelected = ((cell.rowNumber * 4) + index); I declare NSNumber *imageSelected; in my .h

Comment: Try `imageSelected = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger: ((cell.rowNumber * 4) + index)]`.  Remember, NSNumber is an object, so you have to treat it as such.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:2], nil];
```

read it back

```
int i = [[array objectsAtIndex:0] intValue];
```

or successive:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i =0; i<10; i++) {
    NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
    [array addObject: number];
}
```

---

With modern literal syntax you could also do:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [@[@0, @1, @2] mutableCopy];
int i = [array[0] intValue];
```

Comment: thanks. all I needed was a int vector type thing. This did the trick

Answer (score 3):

If you just want a reference to a bunch of pure int constants and want to avoid the overhead of NSNumber objects and don't need to modify your array you can try:

```
const int SOME_NUMBERS[] = {1,2,3};
```

and reference it later on with, e.g.:

```
printf("\nSOME_NUMBERS[1] %i\n",SOME_NUMBERS[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but "It should be dynamic"